# What do they call a small piece of tactics in chess that involves several moves?

Tags: word-request

Imagine you are a professional chess player and you contrive a plot, in which you will get your foe's valuable piece, say, the queen, within more than one move - say, within  3 or 4 moves (each one, of course, followed by your adversary's move). Is there any idiomatic expression or a term in English to refer to such a smart multiple-moves plot in chess?

For example,

> That's another Fisher's brilliant ____________, the target of which we
>   get to realize only now.

Answer (score 2):

If it's about multiple moves by a single piece, the word *maneuver* is definitely appropriate.

Otherwise, a multi-move tactic is often called a [*combination*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Combination_(chess)):

> a **combination** is a sequence of moves, often initiated by a sacrifice, which leaves the opponent few options and results in tangible gain

Answer (score 1):

If, and only if, a combination involves the intentional sacrifice of a piece or a pawn, it is called a *Gambit*. This term is not limited to opening sequences, but the phrase "opening gambit" is common.

This question might get better answers on the Board & card games SE site.

**Edit:** Several dictionaries say that the term 'gambit" is limited to an opening, but all say that it is used only for a sequence in which a pawn or piece is sacrificed for later advantage, usually positional advantage.